# How to avoid dupilcation of tests if I have an abstract class

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

Let’s say I’m writing a car class. It should have the methods configEngine and currentGasolineConsumption beside some other methods. So I refactored out the calculation of the gasoline consumption into an Engine class and use polymorphism to get the current gasoline consumption:

```
class AbstractEngine()
{
    public:
        virtual int calculateGasolineConsumption()
        {
            //... do calculation ...
            return consumption;
        }

        // some other (pure virtual) methodes
};

class EngineA() : public AbstractEngine
{
    public:                              
        // implementation of the pure virtual methodes
};

class EngineB() : public AbstractEngine
{
    public:                              
        // implementation of the pure virtual methodes
};

class EngineC() : public AbstractEngine
{
    public:                              
        // implementation of the pure virtual methodes
        int calculateGasolineConsumption() override 
        {
             //... do new calculation ...
             return consumption;                                 
        }
};
enum EngineType {
    ENGINE_A,
    ENGINE_B,
    ENGINE_C,
};

void configEngine(EngineType engineType)
{
    m_engine = m_engineFactory.create(engineType);
}

int currentGasolineConsumption()
{
    return m_engine.calculateGasolineConsumption();
}
```

Now my question is how to unittest this without getting duplication in my unit tests?

If I write three unittests, for configEngine(ENGINE_A) and configEngine(ENGINE_B) would test basically the same code of the abstract superclass and I don’t like that duplication.

```
struct EngineSpec {
    EngineType engineType;
    int expectedValue;
};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(, tst_car, ::testing::Values(
    EngineSpec { ENGINE_A, 3 },
    EngineSpec { ENGINE_B, 3 },
    EngineSpec { ENGINE_C, 7 }
));

TEST_F(tst_car,
       currentGasolineConsumption_configWithEngine_expectedBehaviour)
{
    EngineSpec engineSpec = GetParam();

    //Arrange
    m_car.configEngine(engineSpec.engineType);

    //Act
    auto result = m_car.currentGasolineConsumption();

    //Assert
    EXPECT_EQ(engineSpec.expectedValue, result);
}
```

Of course there is only one duplicate/unnecessary  unittest but this is only a minimal example. In my real code the number of unit test duplication would explode.

One additional thing: I don’t want to move the Engine class outside of the ‘module’ and use dependency injection because I think this ‘internal Engine class’ approach is easier to handle for the client. So the client has only one interface and some enums to use this module. I would like to treat the Engine class as implementation detail.

Comment: Tests for `configEngine` are super-simple. You mock `m_engineFactory`, tell it to return some engine and that's the end of the story. Each engine subclass tests will most likely cause duplication problem - is that what you are asking here?

Comment: I've just added the code of the parametrized test (google test). It's more about testing currentGasolineConsumption. configEngine is just the arrange...

Answer (score 0):

*Ideally* tests should know as little about the implementation as possible, because 10 years down the line when the abstraction doesn't quite work any more, or is part of a large complicated inheritance chain (e.g. what happens when you get a hybrid engine?) the tests that appear to be a lot of effort right now will still work perfectly.

However, if you want to be pragmatic and don't mind coupling your tests to the implementation a little, you could extract a `testGasolineConsumption(AbstractEngine engine)` method that is called from a test case for each child.  This would check that the implementation works correctly and that the base class behaviour hasn't been overridden.